# Closure of a function: Show equivalence between three definitions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, definition

in a textbook I have found the two equivalent definitions for the closure of a function. However, I struggle to show/see that they re equivalent.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\} $ be a function. Then, the closure of $f$ is the function $\operatorname{cl}(f):\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm\infty\}$  defined as:

(i)
$$\operatorname{cl}(f):= \liminf_{y\to x} f(y) \quad \text{for all }  x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

(ii) Or equivalently,
$$ \operatorname{epi}(\operatorname{cl}(f)) = \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{epi}(f)).$$

(iii) And another definition I have come across:
$$ \operatorname{cl}(f)(x) = \inf\{\alpha: (x, \alpha) \in \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{epi}(f))\}$$

1.) Can someone show the equivalence between (i) and (ii) and the equivalence between (ii) and (iii)?

2.) Can someone tell me why the closure of $f$ might take the value $-\infty$ when $f$ cannot by definition?

Comment: For 2) Take $f(x) = -1/|x|$ for $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$. Then $cl \ f(0)=-\infty$.

Comment: This follows more or less directly from the definitions of inf, liminf, epi, etc. What implication could you prove?

Comment: So personally I still struggle when working with liminf and limsup

Comment: So I tried to prove i) <==> ii) but I didnt know what to do with the liminf